# Blur Camera view In Android

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I want blur camera view like i-OS in android ?  I tried many libraries and code but its not working so how that is possible please suggest me?

Comment: how can i make the duplicate blur surface view. can you explain me please ?  @AksharPatel

Comment: Try this- https://github.com/mmin18/RealtimeBlurView?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=4409

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66389777/8656602